# Data motion scripts and sql compilation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to create re-entrant data motion scripts for updating between versions of my database (via SSDT).

What I was hoping was to just leave all the scripts in, and try to write them 'clever' enough to be run all together (to avoid having to run each update in turn).

So, I have a load of statements like this:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from syscolumns WHERE .... = 'ColumnName')
 BEGIN
     SELECT ColumnName FROM ....
 END
```

But apparently SQL is clever-but-not-enough, and parses this and throws it back at me, saying ColumnName is invalid.

Is there any way round this (apart from EXEC-ing a string)?

Comment: I think in this case you'll need to exec the string. The script assumes that the column exists and fails when it tries to parse it. I'm not quite sure about any other particulars in your scenario, though. Is this part of a post-deploy script?

Comment: @PeterSchott, pre-deployment. Thinking about this over the weekend I realised that having all the scripts for all versions be permanently viable is just too ambitious. A previously deleted table or column could quite well be re-introduced 20 versions hence and screw everything up.